# Find out date and or number of error logs xp_readerrorlog

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, error-log

I have some code to help automate checking the error logs daily on our SQL Server.  This code calls **xp_readerrorlog 0** to check the error log, and **xp_readerrorlog 0,1** to check the SQL Server log.

Sometimes, however, there is more than one error log I need to scan.

I would like to be able to see, by T-SQL, the date of the log or, barring that, find the number of logs that exist.

I read that we can have up to 99 archive logs, but the server throws the following error message when trying to display an error log that doesn't exist.

"xp_readerrorlog() returned error 2, 'The system cannot find the file specified."

I know the date information and number exists since SSMS displays it( see the image below.)

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why it matters if a row you've read from the error log came from Archive #3 or Archive #5? (Since you can just [grab the data from all the logs in one pass](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/187067/1186), and you can easily determine where in that data a log file rollover happened.)

Comment: It doesn't matter other in processing time. My problem is that I'm flying blind.  I know log 0 exists, and probably 1 exists, but after that, I'm shooting in the dark.  If I could know the number of archive logs, that would be enough.  The link you sent only scans the first log (log 0)

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand >>>Since you can just grab the **data from all the logs in one pass**<<< That is wrong. The code from that topic (running xp_readerrorlog without parameters) will read ONLY LAST(current) error log file

Comment: Senior moment I guess. But anyway, why use this undocumented/unsupported XP when you can just read the plain text log files that exist using Powershell or C#?

Answer (score 8):

If you run `EXEC sys.sp_enumerrorlogs;` it will return one row for each log file, the oldest date in the log file, and the log file size.

Which means you can do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #error_log
(
    log_number INT,
    log_date DATE,
    log_size INT
);
INSERT #error_log ( log_number, log_date, log_size )
EXEC ( 'EXEC sys.sp_enumerrorlogs;' );

SELECT *
FROM   #error_log AS el;
```

Then set up a loop to grab the max log number, only grab logs after a certain date, or perhaps exclude logs based on size. Some small logs may be uninteresting, and some large logs may take too long to process.

Comment: Is there a reason for the dynamic SQL?